# Limiting the number of users in a locally hosted R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to limit the number of users of my locally hosted r shiny app to one user at any one time.

So ideally when a second user attempted to run the app at the same time (users access the app by typing the local IP into the address field) the app would display a default message and stop any further progress. Nullifying any other user commands may not matter if the only thing shown upon entry is this denial message.

The content of the app doesn't matter so we can use this app as an example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html

Thanks for any help or info you can give.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to limit users of a website to one at a time? It's a dangerous proposition, since only one errant visitor or Web crawler (ie. Googlebot) could disable the site entirely for actual users.

Comment: Hi, I am creating a locally used tool rather than a website. The app itself won't ever be required to go online because of the data that it accesses. The reason I ask this, is because the app accesses an SQL database via RODBC and runs a query. I am running into issues having more than one application at the same time and this functionality isn't required anyway - its very unlikely there will ever be more than one user at a time and there's a worry many large queries at the same time will slow down the network. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this, I think it's very dangerous, but there are ways you could hack this together.  Here's one solution (as I said, it's hacky and I wouldn't do it myself). The basic idea is to have a global variable that keeps track of whether or not someone is using the app. If nobody is using the app, show the app and turn on the flag and make sure to turn off the flag when the user exits.

```
shinyBusy <- FALSE

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::hidden(
      h1(id = "busyMsg", "App is busy")
    ),
    shinyjs::hidden(
      div(
        id = "app",
        p("Hello!")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    if (shinyBusy) {
      shinyjs::show("busyMsg")
    } else {
      shinyBusy <<- TRUE
      session$onSessionEnded(function() shinyBusy <<- FALSE)
      shinyjs::show("app")
    }
  }
),
launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Note: in order to show/hide app elements, I'm using a package that I wrote [`shinyjs`](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs)

Comment: Hi daattali, many thanks for the solution I will get back to you shortly if i run into any hitches. Could you explain why you wouldn't use this solution? Keen to stay away from anything dangerous!

Comment: Well, first of all, it's pretty annoying for a user. Allowing only one user at a time is very limiting. Secondly, what if someone just opens the webpage and then goes out for dinner, then nobody can access it. Also, I haven't done any robust testing on this, and I don't know if the `onsessionended` is 100% robust. Maybe it's possible that someone accesses the webpage and when they leave for some reason the flag is not reset back to false. I don't know if that can happen, but certainly the first two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. I wonder if there is some possibility of creating 'time-out' functionality in the app to evade the possibility of someone blocking access. Anyway I've decided that i will keep open multiple connections and have found a different solution, but have your code if needed.